# Adding values in a table in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

Trying to get a basic understanding of T-SQL here in SQL Server 2008. Suppose I have a table named "Issues" with columns such as:

```
Priority User
1        Foo
1        Foo
2        Foo
5        Foo
4        Bar
5        Bar
1        Bar
1        Fuz
```

and I wish to display a count of the Priority for each User, along with a breakdown of each Priority, such that the resulting table might be named "Breakdown" might look like

```
User Total 1 2 3 4 5
Foo  4     2 1 0 0 1
Bar  3     1 0 0 1 1
Fuz  1     1 0 0 0 0
```

I was thinking I might declare variables and write my query something like

```
DECLARE @P1 INT
DECLARE @P2 INT
DECLARE @P3 INT
DECLARE @P4 INT
DECLARE @P5 INT

SELECT COUNT(id) AS Total,UserName, 
CASE Priority
 WHEN 1 Then @P1 = @P1 + 1
 WHEN 2 Then @P2 = @P2 + 1
 WHEN 3 Then @P3 = @P3 + 1
 WHEN 4 Then @P4 = @P4 + 1
 WHEN 5 Then @P5 = @P5 + 1
END,
FROM Breakdown
GROUP BY UserName
```

but I'm pretty sure I'm on the wrong track. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks, and sorry for the noobish question; but I'm not sure exactly what to google for here...

-R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT i.user, 
         COUNT(i.priority) AS total,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.priority = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 1,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.priority = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 2,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.priority = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 3,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.priority = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 4,
         SUM(CASE WHEN i.priority = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 5
    FROM ISSUES i
GROUP BY i.user
```

It's a pivot query, converting row data into columnar data.
Not a noob/beginner issue to deal with.  [SQL Server 2005+ added the (now ANSI) PIVOT/UNPIVOT syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), but this is portable to most databases (because few currently support PIVOT/UNPIVOT).

Comment: Thanks so much for the tip. I'm trying to get better at some SQL and was messing around with some example databases for an SSRS report. Thanks again for the assistance everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You need to SELECT one column for each column you want in your result set.  In your SQL, you're only selecting three columns.  Try:

```
SELECT UserName,
       Count(*) AS Total, 
       SUM(CASE Priority WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P1_Total,
       SUM(CASE Priority WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P2_Total,
       SUM(CASE Priority WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P3_Total,
       SUM(CASE Priority WHEN 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P4_Total,
      SUM(CASE Priority WHEN 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P5_Total
FROM Issues 
GROUP BY UserName
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit and adding the 'END' statement. I was messing around in SQL Management Studio and kept wondering why I had a syntax error and was furiously trying to get google to help me.

Comment: Can you tell I don't spend that much time with SQL Server?

Comment: @Randster, you should really mark the other answer correct, it was Ponies who corrected the syntax.

Comment: Done. I marked the first answer as correct since I was pretty sure you had the right answer [before I started trying to key in your text into SQL Management Studio]; but I believe you are kind and correct for me to change the points to OMG Ponies.